# Selenium RC: Need to click <td>

Tags: selenium

We have selection code that is triggered when the empty space in a TD is clicked.  The "onclick=..." is on the TR.

When I get the parent(TD) of an element and click it, it triggers the click on the element and not the TD or TR. So, if the base element is a link, it triggers it.  If the base element is something without an onClick event it does nothing.

I check the tag name of the element that is being clicked and I know that it is the TD. I've also tried to click the row by going up twice, same result.

Any ideas how to trigger the click event on the row???

Example HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="selectRow(this)";>
        <td><a href="something">Link Text</a></td>
        <td><input id="someID" type="text" value="display"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm getting the element for the TD or TR using xpath: "//*[@id='some_id']/.."

Comment: Why do not you use `id`?

Comment: There is not an id on the TD.

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to accomplish. the `td` is a wrapper around `input`. Why you want to interact with `td` but not `input`? And, plus `input` here is a text box so why are you sending click?

Comment: I explain why very clearly, clicking the TD activates the "selectRow()" function that selects the row in our application.But really why does it matter why I want to do it? There should be a way to click the container without clicking the element inside the container.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. I explained that in my answer.

Comment: And, why don't you try sending the click on input instead in that case?

Answer (score 0):

For select ANY element inside of document you can use full or partial xpath.

As example:

```
"/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[6]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]"
```

or

```
".//table/tr[1]/td[2]"
```

and after click as on any another element =)

Full xpath you can generate automatically from firebug/dragonfly/chrome development tools by right click on any tag and select "copy xpath"

Comment: No matter how I get the TD or TR element, the link inside is what is clicked. Besides, this is a dynamic application, I can't use static xpaths to find elements.

Comment: you cannot use full xpath, but  believe you can use partial like ".//table[@id="someId"]/tr[1]/td[2]"

Comment: Finding the element is not the issue, it is what happens when I find the right TD element and click on it and it clicks the element inside the TD.

Answer (score 0):

The possible issue is **NOT** the selector. Issue is the **SIZE** of the element. `Selenium` will not click on an element that is *0* in height/width. The reason the `a` works is because that has some `innerText` and size is not *0*. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: The size of the TD is > zero, I can change the color of its background and see how large it is.

Comment: Try to find the `height` of the element with `Selenium` see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around by generating a JavaScript command that clicks the TD element. Not sure why it works that way but not through the driver, but it does work.

We use Prototype, so if I have the ID:
   $('some_id').up().click()
If I have the text of a link:
   $$("a:contains('Link Text')")[0].up().click()